# generic method to return object to Double or double

Tags: java, generics

I would like to return 2 different types of class (`List<double[]>` or `List<Double[]`) from a single method , as in the below pseudo code. How to achieve this ?

EDITED code and comment : Eclipse does even not allow to compile as this is requested to change the return or data type. I understand YserieScaledCasted will have to be casted manually.

```
protected List<E[]> getYserieRescaledList(Class<E> c) {

    if (Double[].class == c)
        return this.YserieScaled;
    else if (double[].class == c)
        return this.YserieScaledCasted;

}
```

EDIT2: I found the correct to my problem is simply to overload the method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669413/461212).

Comment: *"How to achieve this ?"*  Why to attempt it?

Comment: `double.class`? Did you try to execute your code?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: simply because I work with Double objects in my class but need to give back array list of primitive double to another class.

Comment: I'd just use two methods with different names. `List<double[]>` getXXX()` and `List<double[]> getXXXBoxed`. This isn't really a good use case for generics since there isn't any sensible type relationship you can use between `double` and `Double`; autoboxing is just a compiler "trick".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You realise you are returning a list of arrays, right?  :-)

Short answer:

- even though you are passing in `Class<E>`, you can't use the instanceof operator on a generic type so you can't carry out the if-statement sketched above
- the following is ILLEGAL and doesn't compile at each of the two instanceof operators:

> ```
> class trash {
>     protected <T> List<T[]> getYserieRescaledList(Class<T> cl) {
>        List<T[]> result = null;
>        if (cl instanceof Class<Double>) {
>                result = ...;
>        } else if (cl instanceof Class<double>) {
>                result = ...;
>        }
>        return result;
>     }
> }
> ```

- the reason for this is that generics are a compile-time only construct.  All instantiated generic classes are converted to non-generic classes, with types inserted and type casting carried out etc.    It makes no sense to ask whether a generic class is instantiated with a particular type at runtime - the generic classes have been swapped for non-generic classes
- Instead, cut out the if-statements and simply use the instantiated type to declare variables & arrays, then use your algorithm to populate them and return the result:

> ```
> class treasure {
>     protected <T> List<T[]> getYserieRescaledList(Class<T> cl) {
>        List<T[]> result = null;
>        // apply general algorithm here to populate the array
>        // will work identically whether instantiated with Double or double
>        return result;
>     }
> }
> ```

Longer Answer:

Generic classes should represent "template logic" of generalised processing that can be applied with various specific instantiated types.

Good examples are the java Collections, a persistence query framework (such as JPA Criteria API), a financial calculator for different types of investments, or even a SOA service template with standard service "container" infrastructure logic.

In your case, it might be simpler to use pseudo- method overloading (i.e. two methods with slightly different names):

```
protected List<Double[]> getYserieRescaledList() {
    return this.Y;
}

protected List<double[]> getYserieRescaledList2() {
    return this.YCasted;
}
```

Or even better, just stick to double[] as the only case.  The compiler will transparently do autobox conversions from double to Double as needed when you extract values into other variables/method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Double[].class` and `double[].class`. Note that you can't cast a `Double[]` to a `double[]` and vice versa, you have to manually copy it. So by extension, you can't cast `List<Double[]>` to `List<double[]>` either. **Edit:** though upon a second glance, it appears this may be the limitation you're trying to correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is some interesting stuff going on here. So your `List<double[]>` is an `List<Array>` object where the `Array` contains primitive `double`s.

I would venture to say generics is NOT the right solution here.

I think your best bet is to use the Google Lists library.

something like this:

```
protected List<Double[]> getYserieRescaledList() {
   return this.YseriesScaled;
}
```

Then, whatever calls your `getYseriesRescaledList()` can do something like this to get a `List<double[]>` :

Lists.transform(getYseriesRescaledList(), toPrimitiveDouble());

This will construct a List object in one line of code, using the Function below (from Google Guava):

```
private Function<Double[], double[]> toPrimitiveDouble(){
    return new Function<Double[], double[]>() {
        @Override
        public double[] apply( Double[] doubles) {
            double[] doubleArray = new double[doubles.length];

            int i = 0;
            for (Double doubleObject : doubles){
                doubleArray[i] = doubleObject.doubleValue();
                ++i;
            }

            return doubleArray;
        }
    };
}
```