# method returning dynamic type in java

Tags: java, generics

How can I write a method (if at all i can) that would return a dynamic type

something like

```
public X createRequestObject(Class xclass , String url , String username , String password){
   X x = Class.forName(xclass.getCannonicalName()).getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(url);
   x.setheader("AUTHORIZATION" , createHeader(username,password)
   return x
}
```

and then i can use it like

```
HttpGet httpGet = createRequestObject(HttpGet.class , "http://wwww.google.com , "username","password");

or 

HttpPost httpPost = createRequestObject(HttpPost.class , "http://wwww.google.com , "username","password");
```

I know i can return an object and then cast it later but i dislike casts so wondering if there is a construct in java that can help me do this

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: This post should have the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/java-generics-how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669326/java-generic-return-type   More tips and suggestions there...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply, declare the method as generic, declare its return type, and its class:

```
public <T> T foo(Class<T> clazz, Object... args) {
    return null;
}
```

Obviously the parameters are different that what one would need. You can instantiate a new `T` with:

```
clazz.newInstance();
```

for a nullary constructor.

For a constructor with arguments(in this example String s and Object o):

```
return x.getConstructor(String.class, Object.class).newInstance("s", new Object());
```

In fact, thanks to your varargs you can iterate through the array and get all necessary class objects for the constructor lookup.

You can then safely do:

```
String s = foo(String.class, "a", "b");
```

If you want to constrain T to be a subclass of `HttpRequest` use:

```
public <T extends HttpRequest> T foo(Class<T> clazz, Object... args)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider utilizing a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) in a situation like this.

The factory implementation would be able to take in the type of request that you want and provide you with the request type you need.

> The factory method pattern is an object-oriented creational design pattern to implement the concept of factories and deals with the problem of creating objects (products) without specifying the exact class of object that will be created.

This sounds exactly like what you are trying to do.

Comment: +1 Good idea for what the OP wants. For the limited set, this is perfect. Note that this can't work with an arbitrary class, however.

Comment: Since the poster is specifically trying to work with what seem to be HTTP requests, this solution should suit his needs. It is not quite as flexible as using generics, though.

Comment: And of course, this avoids the unneccessary usage of reflection, to create a class instance.

Comment: @Surveon Yes, exactly. This has its benefits to the problem as well, and should be considered seriously. Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way!

Comment: @hexafraction Cheers! I am fond of your solution in more general situations. There are definitely times where that implementation could come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for generics:

```
public <T extends HttpRequest> T createRequest(Class<T> xclass, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public <X> createRequestObject(Class xclass , String url , String username , String password){

}
```

or

```
public <? extends someSuperclass>  createRequestObject(Class xclass , String url , String username , String password){


}
```

to limit the return type to subclass of some superClass you define.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public <T> T createRequestObject(Class<T> cls, String arg) {

    return TypeT;
}
```