# Generic return type of interface method

Tags: java, generics, interface, java-8, return

I have an interface with method `parse(String value)` and it might have different implementations which return a map of `<String, Integer>` `<String, String>` or anything. How can I make this generic enough so that I extend for different return types?

Currently, I do :

```
public interface Parser <K,V> { 

    Map<K,V> parse(String document);
}
```

But this will make it generic for maps alone. Can someone tell me is there a way I could make it generic for different return types?

Comment: `Parser<T>` perhaps?

Comment: Like `public interface Parser<E> { E parse(String document); }`?

Comment: @4castle I am new to interface, can u explain to me how it works (the one u mentioned here)

Comment: "...is there a way I could make it generic for different return types?" what return types do you mean? Do you have other methods which also need to return generic values which are not related to types returned by `parse` method? Or something else?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java  ... read through. should help you massively with understanding of generics for interface/class

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669326/java-generic-return-type

Comment: If `public interface Parser<E>` is (semantically) what you want, you could also use a [`java.util.function.Function<String, E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), where `E` depicts your return-type (i.e. `Map<K, V>` in your original example).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your interface generic in the return type, I would suggest an extension of JoeC's comment.

Since Java 8, there is the [`java.util.function`-package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), providing interfaces for basic transformation. In particular, the interface [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) can be used to fit your purpose. I would suggest an implementation like this:

```
// file: Parser.java
import java.util.function.Function;

public abstract class Parser<R> implements Function<String, R> {

    @Override
    public final R apply(String document) {
        return (this.parse(document));
    }

    abstract public R parse(String document);
}
```

An instantiation for the above example would look like this:

```
String document             = ...;
Parser<Map<K, V>> mapParser = ...; // instantiate a fitting Parser
Map<K, V> result            = mapParser.parse(document);
```

(Given that `K` and `V` are generic parameters known in this code block).

You could further specify the interface to obtain a somewhat simpler syntax:

```
// file: MapParser.java
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class MapParser<K, V> extends Parser<Map<K, V>> {}
```

With this (empty) interface, you can re-wirte the above code as:

```
String document           = ...;
MapParser<K, V> mapParser = ...; // instantiate a fitting MapParser
Map<K, V> result          = mapParser.parse(document);
```

As mentioned by @matoni, it is possible to write interfaces`IParser` and `IMapParser` and set abstract classes `Parser` and `MapParser` on top of them:

```
// file: IParser.java:
import java.util.function.Function;

public interface IParser<R> extends Function<String,R> {

    @Override
    default public R apply(String document) {
        return (this.parse(document));
    }

    public R parse(String document);
}

// file: IMapParser.java:
import java.util.Map;

public interface IMapParser<K, V> extends IParser<Map<K, V>> {}

// file: Parser.java:
public abstract class Parser<R> implements IParser<R> {

    @Override
    public final R apply(String document) {
        return (this.parse(document));
    }
}

// file: MapParser.java:
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class MapParser<K, V> extends Parser<Map<K, V>>
        implements IMapParser<K, V> {}
```

The interfaces provides more flexibility for the user since one `class` can implement multiple `interface`s, but only `extends` one other `class`. On the downside, however, the developer of interfaces `IParser` and `IMapParser` cannot enforce that method `apply(...)` cannot be overwritten. Thus, in theory, an implementer of `Parser` could implement `apply(...)` and `parse(...)` differently, which could lead to unexpected behaviour. When using abstract classes `Parser` and `MapParser`, the developer does enforce that `apply(...)` calls `parse(...)` and thus consistent behaviour.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as it was the same as yours - you were faster :). Consider to replace abstract Parser by interface Parser. Java 8 introduced `default` methods which are basically the same as non-abstract methods in abstract classes.

Comment: @matoni yes Java 8 does. But with an abstrac class, one can enforce that `apply(...)` does not get overwritten elsewhere and calls `parse(...)`, thus guaranteeing a consisten behaviour, e.g. if an instance of `Parser` is used as part of a stream-call.

Comment: Sure, but in Java everything is virtual thus can be overriden. Final keyword is used rarely. Having an interface is more flexible as you can implement multiple interfaces, while with abstract classes you can extend only one parent class.

Comment: "... in Java everything is virtual..." You mean abstract? It is only abstract if you declare it abstract. This is not the same as dynamic binding. "Final keyword is used rarely." I tend to disagree. Take a look in the API. "Having an interface is more flexible..." sure, but if I can prevent some bugs, I am willing to sacrifice flexibility for correctness.

Comment: By "virtual" I mean overridable. In C++ only methods marked as virtual could be overriden (the same applies for C#), in opposite Java methods are virtual by default. If you are not designing library API I would choose flexibility.

Comment: @matoni I added an interface-layer to my answer. This should satisfy your view, as well as mine and gives the user choice about what to use.

Comment: @matoni: You *can* override C++ methods which are not declared `virtual`, but they will be dispatched based on compile time type only. That’s different to non-overridable methods which can be declared using `const`.

Comment: @Holger You can not override C++ non-virtual methods, only hide super-type methods. Overriding and hidding are two different concepts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to return any type, just define it with one generic type like T:

```
public interface Parser <T> { 

    <T> parse(String document);
}
```

This is possible, but I'm afraid that you will run into a new challenges later. Java currently has now way to instantiate a class from generic type, so you must also pass that class type as a parameter:

```
public interface Parser <T> { 

    <T> parse(Class<T> clazz, String document);
}
```

You can do this, but I think should design you architecture further. If return type from a document can be anything, in most of cases this is a smell of weak design and will lead to a spaghetti code.

Comment: "`Map<T>...`" -> This will not compile. [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) has two generic parameters.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I corrected examples.

Answer (score 0):

The comments already gave you a very good hint, but I guess you need an example.

```
// imports elided

interface Parser<T> {

    T parse(String document);

    Parser<Map<String, Integer>> static mapParser() {
        // replace with actual parsing code
        return document -> {
            Map<String, Integer> result = new Hashmap<>();
            result.put(document, document.length());
            return result;
         }

    Parser<List<String>> static listParser() {
        return document -> Collections.singletonList(document);
    }
}
```

Notice that the implementations are just placeholders - they are just meant to illustrate the Parser types you can create. I also used a lambda which is more concise given that your interface only has one instance method `parse(String document)`, which qualifies it as a `FunctionalInterface`, allowing you to substitute an anonymous lambda expression when implementing the named interface method.

The caller can then call via:

```
String document = "abc";
Map<String, Integer> lookup = Parser.mapParser().parse(document);
List<String> list = Parser.listParser().parse(document);
```